# Dynamically set a canvas width to exactly equal the height without scaling distoration

Tags: html, css, canvas, flexbox

Previously, I was running this javascript to resize the width of my canvas element to the window height:

```
let board = document.getElementById("board");
function resize() {
  // Our canvas must cover full height of screen
  // regardless of the resolution
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  // So we need to calculate the proper scaled width
  // that should work well with every resolution
  var ratio = board.width/board.height;
  var width = height * ratio;

  board.style.width = width+'px';
  board.style.height = height+'px';

  window.display.w = width;
  window.display.h = height;
}

window.addEventListener('load', resize, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
```

Since then my design requirements have evolved to require additional canvases on either side of this one. So I've added

```
<center>
<div class="container">
<canvas id="info" class="panel"></canvas>
<canvas id="board" class="panel"></canvas>
<canvas id="actions" class="panel"></canvas>
</div>
```

and now my canvas draws distorted with the height stretched out. I am trying to draw 5 rows programatically in the canvas code and only 3 are showing.

[image]

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  height:100vh;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.panel {
  display:flex;
}

#board {
  width:50%;
  height:100vh;
  background:#9b59b6;
}

#info {
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
  background:#3498db;
}

#actions {
  width:25%; 
  height:100%;
  background:#1abc9c;
}
```

How do I use flexbox to assign a width to my `board` canvas element such that it won't stretch the drawing?

Previously my drawing had this kind of scale:

[image]

I have also tried setting board's width to 100vh and the result doesn't look much different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `resize()` callback function, also make sure you set the size of the canvas *bitmap*. Currently only the element size is set. This may require some restructuring in regards to how the board is designed, but eliminates the problem you see now.

```
function resize() {
  // Our canvas must cover full height of screen
  // regardless of the resolution
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  // So we need to calculate the proper scaled width
  // that should work well with every resolution
  var ratio = board.width/board.height;
  var width = height * ratio;

  board.width = width;      // make sure bitmap is updated as well
  board.height = height;

  board.style.width = width+'px';
  board.style.height = height+'px';

  window.display.w = width;
  window.display.h = height;
}
```

You can alternatively obtain the canvas element size (CSS) using:

```
var rect = board.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Then set the bitmap size accordingly (be aware of border and padding which do affect the element size):

```
board.width = rect.width;
board.height = rect.height;
```

Comment: aha! display.w and display.h is what I was using to draw. So it looks like I'll have to figure scaling with the width and height..

Comment: @quantumpotato it just means you need to get the proper height from somewhere else (parent element for example), but regardless, the main point is that the bitmap size must be set for canvas. The next issue is to use the correct sizes...

Comment: updated comment, thank you! the width & height of the bitmap are now being set. Now I'm working on fixing the scaling of the actual bitmap drawing

Comment: Accepting as this fixes the layout issue and the remaining problem is in my javascript drawing. Thank you